# Bash literal match

Tags: bash, shell, pattern-matching

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
for i in *.dat;
do
    if [[ "$i" == *(_TEx) ]];then
        file1=$i
    fi
done

echo file1="$file1"
```

I have tested the script with
http://www.shellcheck.net/

```
$ shellcheck myscript
No issues detected!
```

Files

```
262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.dat
262_V01_C01_R000_TEy_BL_2048H.dat
262_V01_C02_R000_THx_BL_2048H.dat
262_V01_C03_R000_THy_BL_2048H.dat
```

But

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/procmt$ bash a8.sh 
file1=
```

Why?

Comment: this means that there are no files matching this pattern

Comment: @JohnKugelman Take a look at my edit,there are 4 files,one matches both conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal modification to your attempt to make it work would be this:

```
    if [[ "$i" == *_TEx* ]]; then
```

i.e. remove the parentheses and add the missing `*` at the end of the pattern. There's no need to set the `extglob` shell option, as you don't need to use any of its features.

However, you might as well change the glob that your are looping over to this:

```
for i in *_TEx*.dat;
```

and avoid the `if` entirely.

Better yet, you could just print the matches directly:

```
shopt -s nullglob
printf '%s\n' *_TEx*.dat # print all files matching the pattern
```

`nullglob` is useful here as it will result in no output when no files match the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

`*(_TEx)` matches a file name that consists solely of the string `_TEx` repeated over and over, as in `_TEx_TEx_TEx_TEx`.

What you're looking for is `*_TEx*`, no extended glob needed. And then you can combine this with the `*.dat` glob and get rid of the loop entirely.

```
echo *_TEx*.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

[Tom Fenech's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874547/45375) and [John Kugelman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874565/45375) show you effective solutions based on *simple* globs.

If you want to use *extended* globbing, as you've attempted (which is *not* necessary with the sample input):

```
[[ "$i" == *@(_TEx)* ]]
```

or, to fold this glob into the loop glob:

```
for i in *@(_TEx)*.dat; do # ...
```

<sup>Assumes `shopt -s extglob`, though note that inside `[[ ... ]]`, extended globbing is *implicitly* turned on in Bash v4.1+ for the RHS of `==` and `!=`.</sup>

---

- Both simple and extended globs match against the *entire* filename, so `*(_TEx)` by itself isn't enough - you must provide enclosing `*` chars. so as to match characters before and after the pattern too.
- Extended-glob construct `*(_TEx)` matches *zero or* more occurrences of `_TEx`, which effectively matches: (a) the empty string, or (b) any number of repetitions of `_TEx`; combined with the enclosing `*` chars., this effectively matches *all* filenames;
  by contrast, `@(_TEx)` matches *exactly one* occurrence of `_TEx` (but, as demonstrated in the referenced answers, simply including `_TEx` in a simple glob does the same.).